# Is the width of a Soxhlet Condenser Inherent to its Function?

Tags: equipment, extraction, distillation, glass

Soxhlet extractors are often coupled to a specifically designed condenser with a very large lower joint.

Is this inherent to it's function as a condenser in the apparatus or only because the Soxhlet Extractor part underneath it needs a big upper joint to get stuff in and out? In other words, is there any drawback to using an adaptor and replacing the condenser by a longer (but thinner) graham condenser?

Preventing flooding might be another reason (for high boiling solvents mainly?).

Comment: The condensate needs to drop into the carboard vessel with whatever you try to extract from! Also, using a Graham condenser for refluxing is a gross piece of lab malpractice. Never use anything but a regular reflux condenser for refluxing! https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/608/choosing-the-right-condenser/41460#41460

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for answering! What about a graham atop a dimroth/allihn? My concern is, can I use a standard width condenser above it, or does it really need to be as large as the soxhlet part? Is there any big drawback to an adaptor?

Comment: No! Put a Dimroth reflux condensor on top of your refluxing setup, and nothing else. If it is too small, use a bigger one. If you think you need to put another one on top as a safety measure, you have already strayed from the path of GLP, don´t do it!

Comment: I'm a stray dog! :D What are the disadvantages of using condensers in series of each other (other than structural/weight-related)? Can I use a long conventional Dimroth vs the unusually "fat" Soxhlet condensers (long vs fat)?

Comment: Of course you can reduce the NS 45 or larger of the Soxleth down to NS 29 of a regular Dimroth. The joint of the soxleth just needs to be so oversized to get the cardboard tube with your material in.

Comment: Yes, excess weight, you need more clamps, which means danger of tension. And stacking condensors is useless.  The first one must be able to do its job. If it floods, then you need one with bigger diameter, or cooler cooling water.

Comment: Give the TA in your lab a kick in the butt from me. Or tell him to send me a check. ;)